# osm store drawn path in database

Tags: java, osmdroid, android-event

Scenario:Using OSM in android ,user draws the path manually on map and clicks on save button, to save in database as a string.

```
        Polyline myPolyline;

      /*
          updating myPolyline  here
      */

      SavePathButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
      {
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {   
                String tempGeoPointString="Begin";
                String fullPathStore="Begin ";
            List<GeoPoint> myPathPoints=new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(myPathOverLay.getNumberOfPoints());
            Collections.copy(myPathPoints, (myPolyline.getPoints()));   
            for (int i = 0; i < myPathPoints.size(); i++) 
            {
                    GeoPoint tempGeoPoint = myPathPoints.get(i);
                    tempGeoPointString=     String.valueOf(tempGeoPoint.getLatitude())+"#"+String.valueOf(tempGeoPoint.getLongitude());
                    fullPathStore=fullPathStore+tempGeoPointString;

            }
        }

    Log.d("Full Path is ",fullPathStore);
    Log.d("PolyLine Size",myPolyline.getNumberOfPoints());
    Log.d("PathPoints size",myPathPoints.size()
    });
```

Here's reference to Polyline [class](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/trunk/OSMBonusPack/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/overlays/Polyline.java?r=266)

myPolyline.getNumberOfPoints() is non zero,but the fullPathStore is not updated and myPathPoints.size() remains zero in the log.
Collecions.copy is not used correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that "Collections.copy(myPathPoints, (myPolyline.getPoints()));" copies properly GeoPoints.

But myPolyline.getPoints() already provides a copy of the polyline points. 
So don't copy it again, wasting time and memory. Just do:

```
List<GeoPoint> myPathPoints = myPolyline.getPoints();
```

Comment: myPathPoints.size() still remains zero and fullPathStore is not updated :(

Comment: I think I have an idea of the root cause (Polyline inheriting from PathOverlay). How do you put your points in the Polyline? with addPoint? If yes, only use setPoints.

Comment: Cannot use setPoints because I'll have only one point to be added to path.

Comment: to add a point: polyline.setPoints(polyline.getPoints().add(newPoint));

Comment: Thanks,that works.`List<GeoPoint> a=myPolyline.getPoints();
  a.add(position);
  myPolyline.setPoints(a);`..Clearpath had problems,so used setPoints() to clear path also..

Comment: New version of OSMBonusPack has been published (v4.6), where Polyline do not inherit from PathOverlay anymore. This will remove this kind of issue (no more access to PathOverlay methods).